# a sequence of characteristic functions converge uniformly to a function (proof)

Tags: real-analysis

> [image]
>    [image]

Attempt: Let $x \in X$. Then, $\varphi_n(x) = k2^{-n}$ $x \in E_{kn}$, and $0$ if $x \not\in E_{kn}$. But, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\varphi_n(x) = 0$ for all $x\in X$. Therefore, $\varphi_n(x)$ uniformly converge to 0 on $E_{kn}$ for all $k$.

In addition, $f(x)$ is defined as $k2^{-n} \le f(x) < (k+1)2^{-n}$. When we take a limit, by squeeze theorem $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in X$.

Is this a complete proof? I think both functions converge uniformly to 0, but how can I connect these two?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: From Bartle's "The Elements of Integration"

Comment: You have made many wrong statements, some even meaningless. If $\lim \phi_n (x)=0$ for all $x$ there is no hope of proving this theorem. The statement $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(x)=0$ does not make sense.

Comment: Since this is one of the most basic results in measure theory I suggest that you can read the proof in the book mentioned by Mason and tell us which particular steps you don't follow.